# Code in MongoDB triggers file is Producing a Customer.findOne() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

In order to be able to compare the pre and post-save version of a document, I am trying to lookup the document in a `pre` hook, and then use that to see what's changed in the doc in the `post` save hook.

But for some reason I'm getting a "Customer.findOne() is not a function" error. This doesn't make any sense to me because I've imported the model into this triggers file, and then, in my function I do this:

```
const Customer = require("../customer");

// Get a version of the document prior to changes
exports.preSave = async function(doc) {
  console.log("preSave firing with doc._id", doc._id); // this ObjectId logs correctly
  if (!doc) return;

  this.preSaveDoc = await Customer.findOne({ _id: doc._id }).exec();
  console.log("this.preSaveDoc: ", this.preSaveDoc);
};
```

Again, this code produces an error:

> "Customer.findOne() is not a function"

FYI, the relevant code in my `Customer` model looks like this:

```
let Schema = mongoose
  .Schema(CustomerSchema, {
    timestamps: true
  })
  .pre("count", function(next) {
    next();
  })
  .pre("save", function(next) {
    const doc = this;
    trigger.preSave(doc);
    next();
  })
  .post("save", function(doc) {
    trigger.postSave(doc);
  })
  .post("update", function(doc) {
    trigger.postSave(doc);
  })
  .post("findOneAndUpdate", function(doc) {
    trigger.postSave(doc);
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Customer", Schema);
```

What am I missing here? Why would this code produce this error on a very standard MongoDB operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get this to work. Instead of looking up the pre-saved/pre-transformed version of the document via Mongoose like this:

```
// Get a version of the document prior to changes
exports.preSave = async function(doc) {
  console.log("preSave firing with doc._id", doc._id); // this ObjectId logs correctly
  if (!doc) return;

  this.preSaveDoc = await Customer.findOne({ _id: doc._id }).exec();
  console.log("this.preSaveDoc: ", this.preSaveDoc);
};
```

... look up the document this way:

```
// Get a version of the document prior to changes
exports.preSave = async function(doc) {
  let MongoClient = await require("../../config/database")();
  let db = MongoClient.connection.db;

  db.collection("customers")
    .findOne({ _id: doc._id })
    .then(doc => {
      this.preSaveDoc = doc;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem has already been solved.

If your mongoDb version is 3.6 or more, you can use [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)

Change streams lets you know what changed in your document. A background process runs in mongoDb which notifies your code an event(CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE) took place and passes you the document. You can filter on your fields to know the exact value.

You can refer this [blog](https://medium.com/@thakkaryash94/mongodb-3-6-change-streams-example-with-node-js-2b9a85652c50)

This is a classic use case where change streams can be applied. Better than reinventing the wheel :)